# Can not accept javascript alert after latest google chrome updates

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use webdriver for my Ui tests.
After latest google chrome updates like 44.0.2403.107 I have problems with accepting alerts:
I use `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();` when I confirm javascript alert, I get *exception: no alert open*. It looks like alert opens later than I try accept it. Does anybody else have the same problem after latest google chrome updates?

I use latest version chromedriver - 2.16.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to include wait for alert as shown below:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

If you still facing issue please raise issue at below URL with sample test code and html file included:
https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/list